# Conditional Expectations & Law of Total Expectation

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, conditional-expectation

I have a question about conditional expectations. In my problem, $X$ and $Y$ and independent standard normal random variables, and $Z = X^3 + Y^2$. I am asked to find $E(Z|X)$.

I was thinking of using the tower property of conditional expectations (or the law of total expectation) to find that:

$$
E(Z) = E[E(Z|X)]
$$

where

$$
E(Z) = E(X^3+Y^2) = E(X^3) + E(Y^2) = 1
$$

using the fact that for standard normal variables, $E(X^3) = 0$ and $E(Y^2) = 1$. This then implies that:

$$
E(Z) = E[E(Z|X)] = 1
$$

which then implies that $E(Z|X) = 1$.

I'm not entirely sure if my approach is "too easy" or if there's an appropriate way of calculating this conditional expectation. Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you cannot do this…always remember expectation is a number, but conditional expectation is a function of random variable x, so also random variable. if the mean weight of men is 200, you cannot say everyone weights 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just write it out:
$$
E[Z\mid X]=E[X^3+Y^2\mid X]=E[X^3\mid X]+E[Y^2\mid X]
$$
the first term is simply $X^3$ for $E[h(X)\mid X]=h(X)$, the second one is $E(Y^2)=1$ by independence.

Comment: That's using the linearity property of expectations, right? I'm sorry if this is a very trivial question. It's been a few years since I've dealt with mathematical statistics. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you mean the first step? yeah, linearity of conditional expectations. and its ok,  maybe reviewing wikipedia is a good way to catch up